# Why getting different Boolean values while using slicing operator for copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why I am getting below behavior in python?

After assigning a in to b I am getting Boolean value "True".

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
```

And assigning with slicing operator I am getting Boolean value "False".

```
>>> b = a[ : ]
>>> a is b
False
```

and also Id of a and b changing if I am using slicing operator as below:

```
>>b = a[ : ] 
>>> id(b)
93006904
>>> id(a)
92963864
```

Comment: How its is duplicate can you explain??. @jpp also that questions suggested by you, in that they are not talking about ID of references after doing copy using slicing operator.

Comment: A copy will have a different id.. why would you expect it to have the same id?

Comment: @jpp why I am getting same Id when I will use 
>>b = a

Comment: Because after the assignment `b = a` both names reference the same object. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks for Doc. @llija Everila. My question is why I am getting different reference ID if I am using slicing operator for assignment?

Comment: Slicing creates an actual copy, a new list object. Assignment just gives names to things (a bit of an over simplification).

Answer (score 0):

You can read `b = a[:]` as making a clone of `a` and naming the clone `b`.

Observe though that the cloning is done only at the outermost list:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a is b
False
>>> a[0] is b[0]
True
```

That is, the contents of the `a` and `b` lists are references to the same object.

In Java you'd have `b = a.clone()` for Python's `b = a[:]`.